# How to access data on raid 0 drives where Windows XP is corrupt?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-xp, raid, data-recovery

Have an old computer where I set up two 80GB HDDs using raid 0 on Windows XP. It's been dormant for several years and decided to see if it still worked but I'm unable to load OS (stuck on windows logo in normal mode and stuck at Mup.sys in safe mode). I'm using a windows xp sp3 cd I found to try and get into recovery mode but that also just hangs on "searching for previous versions of Microsoft Windows". I'm thinking it's because I don't have the 3rd party drivers for the raid hardware anymore (it's onboard raid VIA on a MSI motherboard).

It seems to me that the drives are still intact (raid settings appear to be ok). I would like to verify there is nothing of value (family photos/videos, etc) on the drives prior to reformatting to a standard non-raid setup.

What's the best/safest way to access or recover the data on these drives?

Comment: Boot an alternative OS, either a Windows diagnostic disc, like [Hiren's Boot CD](https://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd), or a Linux live system, like [Ubuntu Mate](http://ubuntu-mate.org/download/) - I suggest the Mate version as being somewhat less unfamiliar to a Windows user.

Comment: Thanks AFH. I forgot to mention I tried to live cd puppy linux but it ALSO got stuck at some point... probably because I got an older version. I'll try Ubuntu Mate first. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: "I don't have the 3rd party drivers for the raid hardware anymore (it's onboard raid VIA on a MSI motherboard)." - So download them from the MSI website.

Comment: If the RAID is implemented in firmware, there should be a prompt to enter the RAID configuration during boot-up (I recall `Ctrl-H` on some boards). This should allow you to check the configuration and maybe run diagnostics.

Comment: Your inability to boot Puppy Linux suggests you may have a motherboard or memory problem. If you have multiple memory cards, try removing some of them or changing their order.

Comment: AFH - I think you might have hit the nail on the head with the memory cards. Removed one and now mini windows xp launched without a hitch on Hiren's. I think this may have worked. I'll report back.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a fakeraid ( software raid implemented in a Windows driver ).  Boot a Linux live cd and it should have no trouble recognizing it and accessing your data.

Comment: Hmm The OP explicitly states "I'm thinking it's because I don't have the 3rd party drivers for the raid hardware anymore (it's onboard raid VIA on a MSI motherboard)"

Comment: It's been so long I assume I had the 3rd party floppy drives but I could be confusing it with an ancient system I had from 3ware that was a PCI card which enabled hardware raid. That for sure had the floppy drives... lol

Comment: @DavidPostill, yes.. I'm aware.  The third party drivers are a Windows only thing.  Linux sees it for what it is: perfectly normal AHIC hardware with software raid on it, and uses the `dmraid` tool to recognize and configure the linux software raid to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You need your SATA RAID drivers to access those disks.

Modify a windows kit and add your SATA/RAID drivers into it so windows setup can recognize the disks. Then reinstall it without formatting anything. You can also load the SATA drivers from an external (USB) FDD unit. Then windows will work and you will be able to access anything.

Even if you connect them to another PC, that one still needs to have drivers compatible with your SATA/RAID.